# Can't connect to AWS instance after import with stock Centos7

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, centos7, import

I am trying to import a Centos7 based VM into Amazon AWS. The VM was created with the Centos7 minimal ISO installed into VirtualBox. Networking in the VM works fine locally before trying to do the import.

I am using the EC2 command line tools to do the import:

```
ec2-import-instance /tmp/ce7-disk1.vmdk -o $AWS_ACCESS_KEY -w $AWS_SECRET_KEY -f vmdk -p Linux -b s3bucket -t m3.medium -a x86_64
```

The import appears to work correctly and I do see a new instance in my list of EC2 instances. After the import indicates that it has successfully completed (using ec2-describe-conversion-tasks) I try to start the instance.

The instance boots correctly and runs, but I seem to have no network connectivity at all. I have all ports forwarded to the instance and I allow all ICMP traffic, but pings and ssh do not show any response.

Here is the console output from the instance:

```
[0.000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[0.000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[0.000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[0.000] Linux version 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015
[0.000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=bfd8bc8f-b9b6-430d-9009-ff4aa05932f4 ro console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto vconsole.keymap=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0.000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[0.000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
[0.000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[0.000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[0.000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000efffffff] usable
[0.000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fc000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[0.000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[0.000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
[0.000] Hypervisor detected: Xen HVM
[0.000] Xen version 4.2.
[0.000] Netfront and the Xen platform PCI driver have been compiled for this kernel: unplug emulated NICs.
[0.000] Blkfront and the Xen platform PCI driver have been compiled for this kernel: unplug emulated disks.
[0.000] You might have to change the root device
[0.000] from /dev/hd[a-d] to /dev/xvd[a-d]
[0.000] in your root= kernel command line option
[0.000] No AGP bridge found
[0.000] e820: last_pfn = 0xf0000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[0.000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
[0.000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fbba0-0x000fbbaf] mapped at [ffff8800000fbba0]
[0.000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]
[0.000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0xefe00000-0xefffffff]
[0.000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0xec000000-0xefdfffff]
[0.000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x80000000-0xebffffff]
[0.000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00100000-0x7fffffff]
[0.000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x36274000-0x37131fff]
[0.000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000ea020 00024 (v02    Xen)
[0.000] ACPI: XSDT 00000000fc00f5a0 00054 (v01    Xen      HVM 00000000 HVML 00000000)
[0.000] ACPI: FACP 00000000fc00f260 000F4 (v04    Xen      HVM 00000000 HVML 00000000)
[0.000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000fc0035e0 0BBF6 (v02    Xen      HVM 00000000 INTL 20090123)
[0.000] ACPI: FACS 00000000fc0035a0 00040
[0.000] ACPI: APIC 00000000fc00f360 000D8 (v02    Xen      HVM 00000000 HVML 00000000)
[0.000] ACPI: HPET 00000000fc00f4b0 00038 (v01    Xen      HVM 00000000 HVML 00000000)
[0.000] ACPI: WAET 00000000fc00f4f0 00028 (v01    Xen      HVM 00000000 HVML 00000000)
[0.000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000fc00f520 00031 (v02    Xen      HVM 00000000 INTL 20090123)
[0.000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000fc00f560 00031 (v02    Xen      HVM 00000000 INTL 20090123)
[0.000] No NUMA configuration found
[0.000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000efffffff]
[0.000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x00000000-0xefffffff]
[0.000]   NODE_DATA [mem 0xeffd8000-0xefffefff]
[0.000] Reserving 161MB of memory at 704MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 3839MB)
[0.000] Zone ranges:
[0.000]   DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
[0.000]   DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff]
[0.000]   Normal   empty
[0.000] Movable zone start for each node
[0.000] Early memory node ranges
[0.000]   node   0: [mem 0x00001000-0x0009dfff]
[0.000]   node   0: [mem 0x00100000-0xefffffff]
[0.000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
[0.000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
-- snip --
[0.000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0e] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)
[0.000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x01] address[0xfec00] gsi_base[0])
[0.000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 1, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-47
[0.000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[0.000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 low level)
[0.000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 low level)
[0.000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 low level)
[0.000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[0.000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[0.000] smpboot: Allowing 15 CPUs, 14 hotplug CPUs
[0.000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009e000-0x0009ffff]
[0.000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
[0.000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
[0.000] e820: [mem 0xf0000000-0xfbffffff] available for PCI devices
[0.000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on Xen HVM
[0.000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:5120 nr_cpumask_bits:15 nr_cpu_ids:15 nr_node_ids:1
[0.000] PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff8800efc00000 s82752 r8192 d23744 u131072
[0.000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 967560
[0.000] Policy zone: DMA32
[0.000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=bfd8bc8f-b9b6-430d-9009-ff4aa05932f4 ro console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto vconsole.keymap=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0.000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[0.000] xsave: enabled xstate_bv 0x7, cntxt size 0x340
[0.000] Checking aperture...
[0.000] No AGP bridge found
[0.000] Memory: 3672904k/3932160k available (6244k kernel code, 396k absent, 258860k reserved, 4178k data, 1604k init)
[0.000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=15, Nodes=1
[0.000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[0.000]     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=5120 to nr_cpu_ids=15.
[0.000]     Experimental no-CBs for all CPUs
[0.000]     Experimental no-CBs CPUs: 0-14.
[0.000] NR_IRQS:327936 nr_irqs:1208 16
[0.000] xen:events: Xen HVM callback vector for event delivery is enabled
[0.000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
[0.000] console [tty0] enabled
[0.000] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
[0.000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[0.000] allocated 15728640 bytes of page_cgroup
[0.000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[0.000] tsc: Detected 2500.058 MHz processor
[0.004] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 5000.11 BogoMIPS (lpj=2500058)
[0.010] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[0.014] Security Framework initialized
[0.017] SELinux:  Initializing.
[0.020] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[0.026] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[0.031] Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096
[0.034] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[0.037] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[0.040] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[0.044] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[0.047] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[0.051] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[0.054] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
[0.057] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
[0.061] mce: CPU supports 2 MCE banks
[0.064] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[0.064] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[0.064] tlb_flushall_shift: 6
[0.086] ACPI: Core revision 20130517
[0.102] ACPI: All ACPI Tables successfully acquired
[0.107] ftrace: allocating 23909 entries in 94 pages
[0.156] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.
[0.162] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=0 pin2=0
[0.184] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz (fam: 06, model: 3e, stepping: 04)
[0.192] installing Xen timer for CPU 0
[0.195] cpu 0 spinlock event irq 69
[0.196] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 62 no PMU driver, software events only.
[0.200] Brought up 1 CPUs
[0.201] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (5000.11 BogoMIPS)
[0.202] NMI watchdog: disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
[0.203] devtmpfs: initialized
[0.205] EVM: security.selinux
[0.206] EVM: security.ima
[0.207] EVM: security.capability
[0.208] atomic64 test passed for x86-64 platform with CX8 and with SSE
[0.209] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[0.210] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[0.211] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[0.212] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[0.213] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[0.214] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[0.215] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[0.216] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[0.220] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[0.221] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20130517/hwxface-571)
[0.224] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20130517/hwxface-571)
[0.227] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[0.228] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[0.229] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[0.291] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[0.292] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[0.293] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[0.294] acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
[0.295] acpiphp: Slot [0] registered
-- snip --
[0.324] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
[0.325] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[0.326] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[0.327] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[0.328] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[0.329] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[0.330] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xf0000000-0xfbffffff]
[0.337] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x10: [io  0x01f0-0x01f7]
[0.338] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x14: [io  0x03f6]
[0.339] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x18: [io  0x0170-0x0177]
[0.340] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x1c: [io  0x0376]
[0.341] * Found PM-Timer Bug on the chipset. Due to workarounds for a bug,
[0.341] * this clock source is slow. Consider trying other clock sources
[0.343] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[0.351] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs *5 10 11)
[0.353] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[0.357] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[0.360] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs *5 10 11)
[0.382] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
[0.383] xen:balloon: Initialising balloon driver
[0.385] xen_balloon: Initialising balloon driver
[0.386] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[0.387] vgaarb: loaded
[0.388] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[0.389] SCSI subsystem initialized
[0.390] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[0.391] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[0.392] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[0.393] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[0.394] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[0.395] NetLabel: Initializing
[0.396] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[0.397] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[0.398] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[0.399] HPET: 3 timers in total, 0 timers will be used for per-cpu timer
[0.400] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
[0.403] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 62.500000 MHz counter
[0.405] Switching to clocksource xen
[0.409] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[0.412] ACPI: bus type PNP registered
[0.415] system 00:00: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
[0.421] system 00:02: [io  0x08a0-0x08a3] has been reserved
[0.425] system 00:02: [io  0x0cc0-0x0ccf] has been reserved
[0.429] system 00:02: [io  0x04d0-0x04d1] has been reserved
[0.434] system 00:0a: [io  0x10c0-0x1] has been reserved
[0.439] system 00:0a: [io  0xb044-0xb] has been reserved
[0.463] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
[0.467] ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
[0.476] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[0.480] TCP established hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[0.485] TCP bind hash table entries: 32768 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[0.490] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
[0.495] TCP: reno registered
[0.497] UDP hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[0.502] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[0.506] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[0.510] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[0.514] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[0.518] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[0.523] Unpacking initramfs...
[0.924] Freeing initrd memory: 15096k freed
[0.931] RAPL PMU detected, hw unit 2^-16 Joules, API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters 163840 ms ovfl timer
[0.938] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306e4, pf=0x1, revision=0x415
[0.942] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[0.948] futex hash table entries: 4096 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[0.953] Initialise system trusted keyring
[0.956] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[0.960] type=2000 audit(1438974112.341:1): initialized
[0.991] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[0.996] zbud: loaded
[0.999] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[1.003] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[1.008] msgmni has been set to 7203
[1.011] Key type big_key registered
[1.014] alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
[1.017] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[1.021] Key type asymmetric registered
[1.024] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[1.028] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[1.033] io scheduler noop registered
[1.036] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[1.040] io scheduler cfq registered
[1.043] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[1.047] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[1.051] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
[1.057] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[1.060] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
[1.065] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
[1.068] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[1.072] xen:grant_table: Grant tables using version 1 layout
[1.076] Grant table initialized
[1.079] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
[1.083] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[1.123] 00:09: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[1.128] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[1.132] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[1.135] crash memory driver: version 1.1
[1.138] rdac: device handler registered
[1.142] hp_sw: device handler registered
[1.146] emc: device handler registered
[1.149] alua: device handler registered
[1.153] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[1.156] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[1.161] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[1.165] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[1.170] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[1.173] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[1.177] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[1.181] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[1.186] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[1.190] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[1.197] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[1.201] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[1.205] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[1.210] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[1.216] rtc_cmos 00:04: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[1.224] rtc_cmos 00:04: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[1.241] cpuidle: using governor menu
[1.244] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[1.248] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[1.252] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[1.256] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[1.260] TCP: cubic registered
[1.263] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[1.266] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[1.270] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[1.273] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[1.277] Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux kpatch signing key: ea0413152cde1d98ebdca3fe6f0230904c9ef717'
[1.283] Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux Driver update signing key: 7f421ee0ab69461574bb358861dbe77762a4201b'
[1.291] Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux kernel signing key: a62a0e1d6a6e484e9bfd7368af34081048e535e5'
[1.298] registered taskstats version 1
[1.303] Key type trusted registered
[1.308] Key type encrypted registered
[1.312] IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[1.316] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vfb/0
[1.321] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vbd/768
[1.326] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vbd/51728
[1.331] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vif/0
[1.336] rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2015-08-07 19:01:53 UTC (1438974113)
[1.342] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1604k freed
[1.348] systemd[1]: systemd 208 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ)
[1.358] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization 'xen'.
[1.362] systemd[1]: Running in initial RAM disk.
[1.370] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <solace-vmr>.
[1.402] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bfd8bc8f\x2db9b6\x2d430d\x2d9009\x2dff4aa05932f4.device...
[1.421] systemd[1]: Starting -.slice.
[1.427] systemd[1]: Created slice -.slice.
[1.431] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[1.438] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[1.444] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[1.451] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[1.454] systemd[1]: Starting Timers.
[1.460] systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
[1.465] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[1.471] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[1.475] systemd[1]: Started dracut ask for additional cmdline parameters.
[1.481] systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
[1.487] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[1.499] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[1.519] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[1.525] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[1.540] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[1.939] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2499.999 MHz
[2.037] systemd-udevd[225]: starting version 208
[2.228] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
[2.242] xen_netfront: Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver
[2.443] scsi host0: ata_piix
[2.456] scsi host1: ata_piix
[2.460] blkfront: xvda: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[2.470] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc100 irq 14
[2.475] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc108 irq 15
%GStarted Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[    2.527]  xvda: xvda1 xvda2 xvda3 xvda4 < xvda5 >
[2.536] Setting capacity to 39845888
[2.539] xvda: detected capacity change from 0 to 20401094656
Reached target Paths.
Reached target Basic System.
[2.554] blkfront: xvdb: flush diskcache: enabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[2.562]  xvdb: unknown partition table
[2.568] Setting capacity to 8377344
[2.571] xvdb: detected capacity change from 0 to 4289200128
Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/bfd8bc8f-b9b6-430d-9009-ff4aa05932f4.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/bfd8...ff4aa05932f4...
Started dracut initqueue hook.
Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Reached target Remote File Systems.
systemd-fsck[267]: /dev/xvda2: clean, 27031/753664 files, 326629/3014656 blocks
Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/bfd8b...9-ff4aa05932f4.
         Mounting /sysroot...
[3.181] EXT4-fs (xvda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mounted /sysroot.
Reached target Initrd Root File System.
         Starting Reload Configuration from the Real Root...
Started Reload Configuration from the Real Root.
Reached target Initrd File Systems.
Reached target Initrd Default Target.
[3.517] systemd-journald[122]: Received SIGTERM
[4.180] type=1404 audit(1438974116.343:2): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
[4.501] type=1403 audit(1438974116.664:3): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
[4.513] systemd[1]: Successfully loaded SELinux policy in 355.584ms.
[4.678] systemd[1]: Relabelled /dev and /run in 29.026ms.

Welcome to CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Stopped Switch Root.
Stopped target Switch Root.
Stopped target Initrd File Systems.
         Stopping File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/bfd8...ff4aa05932f4...
Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/bfd8b...9-ff4aa05932f4.
Stopped target Initrd Root File System.
Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
         Expecting device dev-ttyS0.device...
Created slice system-getty.slice.
Created slice User and Session Slice.
Reached target Remote File Systems.
Reached target Slices.
Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats F...utomount Point.
Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Starting Create list of required static device nodes...rrent kernel...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Mounting Debug File System...
Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
Listening on udev Control Socket.
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
         Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. ...ress polling...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-91880d70\x2d9cd...fb664.device...
         Starting File System Check on Root Device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-04756585\x2db03...e40ad.device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b5d5116f\x2d075...1945c.device...
Stopped Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
         Stopping Journal Service...
Stopped Journal Service.
         Starting Journal Service...
Started Journal Service.
Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Mounted Debug File System.
Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Started Create list of required static device nodes ...current kernel.
         Starting Create static device nodes in /dev...
         Starting LVM2 metadata daemon...
Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Started Create static device nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Started udev Kernel Device Manager.[    6.078] systemd-udevd[366]: starting version 208

Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. u...ogress polling.
systemd-fsck[347]: /dev/xvda2: clean, 27031/753664 files, 326629/3014656 blocks
Started File System Check on Root Device.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[6.134] EXT4-fs (xvda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
         Starting Configure read-only root support...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Started Configure read-only root support.
[6.471] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
[6.524] FDC 0 is a S82078B
[6.620] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input4
Found device /dev/ttyS0.
[6.758] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
%G[    6.788] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[6.945] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/b5d5116f-075e-4afb-9df4-acb2ca61945c.
         Mounting /usr/sw/internalspool...
Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/04756585-b03f-4156-9cee-625cd2ae40ad.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0475...625cd2ae40ad...[    9.642] Adding 2097148k swap on /dev/xvda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2097148k SSFS

Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/91880d70-9cda-4ad4-8374-cbf6ff0fb664.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/91880d70-9cda-4ad4...cbf6ff0fb664...
Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/91880d70-9cda-4ad4-8374-cbf6ff0fb664.
Reached target Swap.
[9.698] EXT4-fs (xvda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mounted /usr/sw/internalspool.
systemd-fsck[434]: /dev/xvda1: clean, 340/51200 files, 115304/204800 blocks
Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/04756...e-625cd2ae40ad.
         Mounting /boot...
[9.818] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mounted /boot.
Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Import network configuration from initramfs...
[9.844] systemd-journald[348]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
         Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Started Import network configuration from initramfs.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Security Auditing Service...
[10.261] type=1305 audit(1438974122.425:4): audit_pid=465 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
Started Security Auditing Service.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown...
Started Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown.
Reached target System Initialization.
Reached target Timers.
Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Reached target Sockets.
Reached target Paths.
Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting NTP client/server...
         Starting irqbalance daemon...
Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Login Service...
Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Command Scheduler...
Started Command Scheduler.
         Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
Started Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
[11.775] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

centos-host login:
```

I am not importing this into a VPC, but as far as I can tell I do not need to. According to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ImportingYourVM.html) the new instance should get a public IP, which is what I want to start with.

Does anyone have a suggestions of things to try or ways to increase the console output to indicate what the issue might be?

Comment: Note that I snipped the console log in a couple of places to get me question to fit into the 30k char limit. I also trimmed the timestamp size at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Try assigning an elastic IP and access it that way.

Comment: The instance does already have an IP address (and DNS name) assigned to it. The problem is that I can't ping, ssh (or telnet <IP> 22) to it. I did try creating an elastic IP, but the tool didn't seem to allow me to assign it to any of my instances (even ones that weren't imported and don't have any connectivity issues) - I will look into that and see if I can fix this and try your suggestion.

Comment: I have also tried importing into a VPC, configuring an elastic IP associated with the instance. I do have an internet gateway configured and another (non-imported) instance in that same subnet is reachable. Alas, still no connectivity to the imported instance.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to install cloud-init in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you configure the eth0 before importing the machine (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 if I recall well on Centos)? it should look something similar to:

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=yes
IPV6INIT=no
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=yes
```

(check especially IPV6INIT setting)

Also make sure iptables service is off at boot time(run "sudo chkconfig iptables off" before importing the machine), and security group is opened for your ec2 instance

Comment: Yup - that was the problem (missing ifcfg-eth0 script). It surprises me because I had added net.ifnames=0 to the boot line to have eth0 as the interface name in my local VM, but for some reason the local VM appears to be working within the ifcfg-eth0 script. Thanks!